# Retrieve status of automations of all child BUs from enterprise BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, automation

Below is the code which I tried, but when the automation is erroring out the status is populating as paused, scheduled, stopped. The error status is not population.

Code:

```
<style>
    body, a, input, td, th {font-family:sans-serif; font-size:12px;}
</style>



<script runat="server">

  Platform.Load("core","1");

  var debug = false;

  try {

    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var mids = [XXX,YYY];   //eight mid values

    if (debug) {
      Write("<br>mids: " + Stringify(mids));
    }

    Write("<table border='1'>");
    Write("<tr>");
    Write("<th>MID</th>");    
    Write("<th>Automation Names</th>");
    Write("<th>BU Names</th>");
    Write("<th>Status</th>");
    Write("<th>NextScheduleTime</th>");
    Write("</tr>");

    for (i = 0; i < mids.length; i++) {

      var mid = mids[i];
      prox.setClientId({"ID": mid});
      var obj = "Automation";

      var cols = ["ProgramID","CustomerKey","Status","Name","ScheduledTime"];

      // The only supported operators for the Automation object are: IN, EQUALS. Complex filter is not supported.
      // https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/automation.htm

      var filter = {
          Property: "Status"
          , SimpleOperator: "IN"
          , Value: [-1,2,5,3,6,7]
      };

      var opts = null;
      var props = null;

      var moreObjs = true;
      var reqID = null;

      while (moreObjs) {

          moreObjs = false;

          var objs = reqID == null ? prox.retrieve(obj, cols, filter, opts, props) : prox.getNextBatch(obj, reqID);

          if (objs != null) {

              moreObjs = objs.HasMoreRows;
              reqID = objs.RequestID;

              for (var j = 0; j < objs.Results.length; j++) {

                var automationObj = objs.Results[j];

                var statusDsc = "";
                var buDsc = "";

               switch (automationObj.Status) {
                  case -1: statusDsc = "Error";
                    if(mid==XXX)
                      buDsc="Production";                   
                      else
                      buDsc="Developement";
                   break;
                  case  3: statusDsc = "Running";
                       if(mid==XXX)
                      buDsc="Production";                   
                      else
                      buDsc="Developement";
                   break;
                  case  6: statusDsc = "Scheduled";
   if(mid==XXX)
                      buDsc="Production";                   
                      else
                      buDsc="Developement";
                   break;
                   case  2: statusDsc = "Ready";
   if(mid==XXX)
                      buDsc="Production";                   
                      else
                      buDsc="Developement";
                   break;
       case  5: statusDsc = "Stopped";
  if(mid==XXX)
                      buDsc="Production";                   
                      else
                      buDsc="Developement";
                   break;
                  case  7: statusDsc = "Awaiting Trigger"; 
                      if(mid==XXX)
                      buDsc="Production";                   
                      else
                      buDsc="Developement";
                   break;
                }

              Write("<tr>");
                Write("<td>" + mid + "</td>");
                Write("<td>" + automationObj.Name + "</td>");
                Write("<td>" + buDsc + "</td>");
                Write("<td>" + statusDsc + "</td>");
                if(statusDsc == "Stopped" || statusDsc == "Ready" || statusDsc == "Scheduled" ||  statusDsc == "Error" || statusDsc == "Running") 
                 {                       
                      schTime=automationObj.ScheduledTime;
                      Write("<td>" + schTime + "</td>");   
                 } 
                Write("</tr>");

              }

          }


      }

      prox.resetClientIds();

    }

    Write("</table>");

  } catch (e) {

    if (debug) {
      Platform.Response.Write("<br><br>e: " + Stringify(e));
    }

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the status of the automations, you need to retrieve on the [Automation Instance Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/automationinstance.htm).

Below is the sample code, which fetches all the automations in all the BUs and checks the status of the automations in last 24 hours.

```
    //Automation Instance
    function AutomationInstance(CustomerKey,mid,marketName,foldername)
{
          var childreqID = null;
          var childprops = null;
          var childmoreObjs = true;
          prox.setClientId({"ID": mid});
       var AutomationInstance = "AutomationInstance";
          var childcols = ["CustomerKey","Status","StartTime","StatusLastUpdate","Name"];  
                    var childfilter = {
          
                    Property:"CustomerKey",
                    SimpleOperator:"IN",
                    Value:  CustomerKey //Passing more than one automation
                };

      try{
                  
        while (childmoreObjs)
        {
            childmoreObjs = false;
            var childobjs = childreqID == null ? prox.retrieve(AutomationInstance, childcols, childfilter) : prox.getNextBatch(childobjs, childreqID);
          if (childobjs != null) 
            {
             childmoreObjs = childobjs.HasMoreRows;
         childreqID = childobjs.RequestID;
           var resultsStore = [];          
            for (var u = 0; u < childobjs.Results.length;u++)
              {  
                       var automationInsitanceObj = childobjs.Results[u]; 
                       var StartTime = automationInsitanceObj.StartTime;       
                       var customerkey = automationInsitanceObj.CustomerKey;
                       var instancestatus = automationInsitanceObj.Status;  
                       var AutomationName = automationInsitanceObj.Name
                       var today = new Date();
                       var prevDate = new Date();
                       var yesterday = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000*60*60*24);
                       prevDate.setDate(today.getDate()-1);
     
          if(StartTime >= yesterday && instancestatus == -1)
           {                 
           var rows  = Platform.Function.UpsertData('Automation_Monitoring',['MID','CustomerKey'],[mid,customerkey],['Status','ErrorDate','AutomationName','BusinessUnit','FolderName'],["Error",StartTime,AutomationName,marketName,foldername]);    
           }         
           
         }//end for       
             }//end if
                  }// end while
                }// end try
               
  catch (e) {
      Platform.Response.Write("child object error for" + Stringify(e)); 
  }
       prox.resetClientIds();
     }// end function
```

Comment: Thank you @Swathi but i dont want to hardcode the CustomerKey and so i have to create an DE "Automation_Monitoring " to capture the details?

Comment: Storing the details in a Monitoring DE is optional. But what you need, is to reterive the automation object, fetch all the automations and pass in all the customerkey as an array!

Comment: @Swathi I tried the above code in enterprise bu and tried fetching the child bu error status I was not able to achieve it

Comment: Are you passing the right mid?

Comment: Yes the status was population as schedule when it changed to error status it did not populate in the cloud page

Comment: What's the error you are getting? May be post your code in the question and we can check what's happening?