# SFMC system performance reports

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am looking to implement a solution to report on Salesforce marketing cloud system performance.
For example:

- journey froze and stopped injecting records
- automation paused/stopped running
- communications (email,sms,push) failed sending

has anyone done something similar?
I believe I could look into data views for emails sends, but not sure how I could access the status of journeys and automations

Answer (score 0):

For Automations, you have to built a custom solution using ssjs. This [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/330708/retrieve-status-of-automations-of-all-child-bus-from-enterprise-bu/330710#330710) might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can set up "priority" data extensions in another DE for lookup - then use SSJS to find last run date, status, etc..

Another portion to consider is finding email sends/opens/ etc. - that will often be a good clue into what is going on.  If your send log includes other attributes you could include those in the logic as well but the basics are here: https://learningcurv.com/salesforce-marketing-cloud-create-custom-report - some errors in this tutorial but if you set it up step-by-step you will be able to find/fix those errors.

Hope this helps!